# Is it possible to change Status Bar color for all view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, statusbar, uicolor

I have been searching for a while now and I only found answers that describe to change color on one view controller not for all view controllers.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the style of the status bar in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    return true
}
```

And add the following code to your `Info.plist`:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: Apparently this is deprecated since iOS 9.0…

Answer (score 13):

Only two steps are needed to change the status bar style for the entire app.

## Step 1

Add a new property to the project's `Info.plist` file and set it to `false`.

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

## Step 2

Go to your project's target and under *General / Deployment Info*, switch `Status Bar Style` from `Default` to `Light`.

[image: The Status Bar Style option can be found right under the device orientation selectors of the Xcode project's editor.]

Doing these steps will ensure the status bar behaves the same in the entire project.

Answer (score 2):

First in **info.plist** set View controller-based status bar appearance to **NO**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
   if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    return true
}
```

The output screenshot is below
[image]

Comment: isn't this a hack & app might get rejected for it?

Comment: yes...I saw multiple answers telling it...Just see one of the answers above too..

Answer (score 2):

You can set background color for status bar during application launch or during viewDidLoad of your view controller.

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}

// Set upon application launch, if you've application based status bar
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return true
    }
}


or 
// Set it from your view controller if you've view controller based statusbar
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Here is [Apple Guidelines/Instruction](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/) about status bar change. Only Dark & light (while & black) are allowed in status bar.

*Here is - **How to change status bar style**:*

If you want to set status bar style, application level then set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your `.plist' file.

Or programatically you can do it from app delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    return true
}
```

if you wan to set status bar style, at view controller level then follow these steps:

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file, if you need to set status bar style at UIViewController level only.
2. In the viewDidLoad add function - `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle in your view controller.

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Set value of .plist according to status bar style setup level.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4
In AppDelegate.swift add this extension:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this should be the nowadays accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
Step 1:
Open your info.plist and insert a new key named "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO

Step 2:
Open the `viewcontroller` file where you want to change the statusBarStyle and put the following code in `viewWillAppear()`,

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Step 3 :

Also, implement the `viewWillDisappear()` method for that specific viewController and put the following lines of code,

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default
}
```

All the best

Answer (score 0):

## Important clarification

It is very important to understand two approaches to customizing the status bar.

> Is it possible to change Status Bar color for all view controllers?

Boolean answer is **Yes**, but, **in legal way**, it is so close to **No** that answering Yes is provocative if you need colors other that black or white.

There are two approaches when it comes to customizing Status bar appearance.

### First approach – one color for whole app

In info.plist you find or create a key called

`View controller-based status bar appearance`

and set it to **NO**.

What it does? It essentially establishes a setting that says that in your application, status bar appearance **is not defined individually by each view controller**. This is super important to understand. This means that you have uniform setting for entire app, for all screens. This is what you needed. But. You are limited to only two settings: white and black. And there's no way you can customize it using documented API.

To set this up:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    return true
}
```

### Second approach – individual color for each view controller

This is the opposite. To make it work, go ahead to info.plist and set

`View controller-based status bar appearance`

to **YES**

This way, whenever a new view controller is open, status bar style is set individually if you insert this implementation in each `UIViewController` instance you need:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

You have the same as in first, set either dark or light style for statusbar.

### Third approach – Hack!

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if let statusbar = value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
        statusbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    return true
}
```

Why hack? If you need status bar color other than black or white. Here you use undocumented API. You get statusBar object using KVC and manually set its color. This is dirty, not legal way, but so far it's the only way to set up custom color for statusbar. It may well lead your app to being rejected. But maybe you're lucky. In order to set it once and for all, you will need to set to NO the aforementioned flag so that status bar did not initialize its style with each view controller.

Comment: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key statusBar. Any solution?